# Conditional Expectation in a Fixed Effects model

Tags: econometrics, fixed-effects-model, conditional-expectation

In Mostly Harmless Econometrics, pp. 222 - 223, I'm struggling to understand a derivation. Specifically, I don't know how 5.1.2 implies 5.1.3 below.

[image]

Further, they claim that
$$
\varepsilon_{it} \equiv Y_{0it} - E(Y_{0it} | A_i, X_{it}, t) 
$$

My attempt went as follows:

$$
Y_{it} = Y_{0it} + D_{it}(Y_{1it} - Y_{0it}) = E(Y_{0it} | A_i, X_{it}, t) + D_{it}(Y_{1it} - Y_{0it}) + Y_{0it} - E(Y_{0it} | A_i, X_{it}, t) 
$$
However, $\rho$ is only defined over expectations (i.e. we do not have $Y_{1it} - Y_{0it} = \rho$), and therefore I do not know how they arrive at 5.1.3